Accounting for Impact of Vbe Saturation Variability in N-Channel BJT Circuit
I have been working on an automatic gain control circuit which is shown in the image below.

The rational of the AGC is that larger signals at v_out will allow the PNP Transistor Q4 to conduct current from ground to the collector of Q4 raising the negative voltage from V6 to ground. Depending on the amplitude of the signal at Q4s base the portion of time that Q4 is conducting will increase/decrease. Larger (high amplitude) signals will ultimately lead to a higher (closer to 0V) signal at the gate of the N-channel JFET J2. The higher the voltage at J2's gate the lower its resistance. When J2 has a low resistance there is a large voltage drop across R10 which leads the signal v_oa_in to be smaller. The output v_out can be seen in the image below.

For the PNP Transistor Q4 I am planning to use the 2N3906 transistor. However when I look at the variability in Vbe per the datasheet it can vary from 0.65 to 0.85V. Datasheet. Leftmost column is minimum, rightmost column is maximum

I am a little confused about this number though because it is specified for a base current of 1 mA and a collector current of 10 mA. My circuit is not drawing nearly this much current. Per the image below my max base current is about 0.2 mA and my max collector current is 1.3 mA. My first question then is does the 0.65 to 0.85 voltage range still apply or will it vary based on the current being drawn by the collector/base. Based on the next line which gives the variability for 5mA base and 50mA collector current as having a max of 0.95 it must vary to some extend based on the current flowing through the transistor.
Question 1. Will the bounds of Vbe decrease if Q4 draws less current through the base/collector
The primary reason I care about this is that if I understand things correctly adjusting Vbe will likely impact the time that the BJT is conducting current "ON" which will ultimately lead to variations in the gate voltage at the N-JFET, which could disrupt how the AGC current works

Now assuming that the range of the voltages really is 0.65 to 0.85 how would I go about modelling this. I didn't see any parameters in the the spice model of the 2N3906 that stood out as representing Vbe saturation. I also don't know what the typical Vbe saturation is for 2N3906, I believe it is 0.7V for most PNPs, but the linked datasheet does not give a typical value. If I did know the typical Vbe I could always adjust the voltage at Q4's base using a circuit like the one below to simulate varying Vbe saturation.

If I do this and adjust the voltage V1 from -0.4 to 0.4V which should result in a voltage of +/- 0.2V at the BJT's gate. I don't see that many appreciable differences in the output signal when V1 is -0.4. In the 0.4V case I do appear to see some modulations start to occur for the smallest input voltages (when attenuation from voltage divider should be the smallest).
If I plot the gate voltage for the two cases and focus on the smallest input voltage of 5 mV then for the case without the 0.4V offset the mean and peak to peak steady state gate signal are -2.0143V and 0.0286V respectively. In the case the 0.4V offset is present these values become -2.0265 and 0.0358V. This isn't surprising as the 0.4V offset leads the BJT to conduct current for shorter amounts of time leading to an overall lower voltage and a greater swing in voltage as the time for the LPFs capacitors to discharge is longer. The reason the stability



The instability also makes sense if we look at the resistance vs gate voltage plot below. As the voltage gets lower at the gate the resistance appears to increase exponentially which means that even for the same peak to peak variation in gate voltage the resistance variation will increase if the mean/DC offset voltage decreases which is what happens when V1 is set to 0.4V.

My second question then is, was the use of V1 to model variations in Vbe a valid approach? Even if it was a valid approach are there better ways to model these variations in the 2N3906 model itself?
Thank you in advance.

Not your question, but the BE junction of Q4 takes only the negative half wave coming from C1. You should add a reverse diode parallel to the BE junction, that takes the positive half wave, or C1 accumulates charge and the regulation loop will drift away.
